# Adding gradient layer is causing images not to show in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

Very new to this so forgive me if this is too easy. I created a gradient background for my VC and since then none of my Images on my storyboard are showing when I run the app. I attached my code and feel free to correct me.

```
class whoVC: UIViewController {







func setGradientBackground() {
    let colorTop =  UIColor(red: 119.0/255.0, green: 56.0/255.0, blue: 109.0/255.0, alpha: 2.0).cgColor
    let colorBottom = UIColor(red: 185.0/255.0, green: 89.0/255.0, blue: 127.0/255.0, alpha: 2.0).cgColor

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.colors = [ colorTop, colorBottom]
    gradientLayer.locations = [ 0.0, 1.0]
    gradientLayer.frame = self.view.bounds

    self.view.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)





}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    setGradientBackground()
}




override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: Reorder sublayers.

Comment: how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You are saying:

```
self.view.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
```

That means to put a sublayer in front of all other existing sublayers. But your subviews *are* sublayers. Therefore the gradient covers all your subviews. If that's not what you want, don't do that.

Comment: so removing self.view.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer) will help ? I did that and the gradient didn't work. So I A am assuming I did this wrong.

Comment: Reorder the sublayers

Answer (score 0):

To put the layer to the background, you should use insertSubLayer instead of addSubLayer

```
view.layer.insertSublayer(yourLayer, atIndex: yourIndex)
```

The index of the layer should be 0